# TestCafe config setup for multiple environments

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a single .testcaferc.json file that provides config for all environments?

We've got a lot of config that's shared, so I don't really want to create individual config files for each environment if I don't have to.

Something like this would be great, but can't seem to see anything in the tc docs that mentions anything about environments

```json
{
  browsers: "chrome",
  concurrency: 5,
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
  ...
  env: {
    dev: {
      baseUrl: "https://dev.example.com",
      ...
    },
    test: {
      baseUrl: "https://test.example.com",
      ...
    },
    prod: {
      baseUrl: "https://example.com",
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

Currently we pass a number of extra args into the scripts as below, which is getting really messy and difficult to maintain in our package file.

```json
{
    "test:e2e": "npm run test:cafe",
    "test:e2e:dev": "npm run test:cafe -- --base-url=https://dev.example.com",
    "test:e2e:test": "npm run test:cafe -- --base-url=https://test.example.com",
    "test:e2e:prod": "npm run test:cafe -- --base-url=https://example.com","
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JavaScript config](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#javascript) file instead of a [JSON config file](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#json). In this case, you can write your own logic right inside the config. For example, you can check the environment variable as follows:

.testcaferc.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    baseUrl:      process.env.dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'http://localhost:3005', 
    customActions: {},
}
```

Moreover, you can create different configuration files for different environments, and one for common settings. In this case, you can use the common settings from the common config file and import specific environment settings from other config files.

**Common: .testcaferc.js**

```js
function resolveEnv () {
    if (process.env.dev)
        return './.testcaferc-dev.js'
    else if (process.env.test)
        return './.testcaferc-test.js'
    else
        return './.testcaferc-prod.js'
}

 

const commonConfig = {
    skipJsErrors: true,
    customActions: {}
}

 

const envConfigName = resolveEnv();
const envConfig     = require(envConfigName);

 

module.exports = {
    ...commonConfig,
    ...envConfig,
}
```

**.testcaferc-dev.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    skipJsErrors: false,
}
```